# naming paths inside a TikZ foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

Is it possible to create named paths inside a foreach loop with the name depending on the counter?

I want to write something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
        \draw[name path=line\i] (-3,-\i) -- (3,\i);
    \draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2}] (intersection-1) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but this throws the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \OT1\i 
l.11    \draw (0,3) circle (3);
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It also possible a bit less hacky. (pgf-manual p. 496) Look at this modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
    {
  \draw[name path global/.expanded=line\i] (-3,\i) -- (3,-\i);
    }
\draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2}] (intersection-1) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, that's indeed very elegant.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 16):

I've found that when passing options to TikZ elements as macros then I need to expand the macro before passing it in:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
{
  \edef\optname{name path global=line\i}
  \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\optname] (-3,\i) -- (3,-\i);
}
    \draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2}] (intersection-1) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now that I've looked up what naming paths does, I notice that the first version of this wouldn't have worked because the path naming occurred within a foreach loop, and that's a local scope.  So the path names don't survive to the "outside".  This is true even if the `\foreach` is a one-liner (so no curly braces).  To verify this, one can simply do:

```
\foreach \i in {1}
  \draw[name path=line] (3,1) -- (-3,-1);
```

and then try to refer to the `line` path.  TikZ will complain.

The solution to this is to use the `name path global` key instead.  This makes the path name available For All Time (well, for the whole picture).  Whereupon, it works.

Here's the result of the above:

[image]

Comment: This compiles and it sometimes works as expected. If I plug it into the example above tikz says that line1 as unknown. When I add an unrelated drawing statement between the loop and the example, it works as expected. In the more complicated picture where I actually want to use this, I can never get it to work.

Comment: @Caramdir: Looking at the manual, I see that path names are only local unless declared otherwise.  So I think you need to use `path name global`.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I'm somewhat embarrassed that I missed the `path name global` option.

Comment: I have used this solution to name paths, but I couldn't use those names for intersections in a call to `pgfplotsextra`, as in `\edef\extraopts{name intersections={of=\line\i and refLine}}`.

Comment: @Christoph: I'd need to see the full code that you were trying.  It's probably best to ask a follow-up question (refer to this one, of course).

Comment: @ Andrew Stacey: Here it is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43950/pgfplots-using-path-names-created-with-foreach-in-pgfplotsextra