# Drawing lines between 2 intersections of a function given the y-value (Morse potential)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to draw lines (vibrational energy lines) in a Morse potential curve.

Let me explain it with a more general example :

If I have a parabola x², I want to draw lines in it given a set of y values, for instance (1; 0.5; 0.7; 0.8; 0.85; 0.875). How can I draw these lines up to the intersection? For example, how can I find the x values to draw the first line from (-1,1) up to (1,1)?

My intention is to draw a figure like this

[image: Morse potentials]

Comment: If you add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you've done, it's so much appealing to us for provide a fast and good answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated**

### Method 1: using `intersections` library

Here's an approach that uses `pgfplots` to plot the actual Morse potential. It uses `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` to define a potential function `V` and another function that calculates the energy of the nth bound state, then uses the `tikz` library `intersections` to calculate the intersection of an undrawn horizontal line at this height with the Morse potential. Finally, it draws the horizontal line from one intersection to the next. See [pgfplots: using path names created with foreach in pgfplotsextra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43950/pgfplots-using-path-names-created-with-foreach-in-pgfplotsextra) for info on naming paths within `pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%% Define Potential Function %%%%%%%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\De}{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\re}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{V}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    \De*((1-exp(-\a*(#1-\re)))^2-1)
    }%
}
%%%%%%% Energy Levels %%%%%%%
% energies are given as multiples of \hbar \omega_0 with
% \omega_0 = \a*sqrt(2*\De/\m), where m is the (reduced) mass of the diatomic molecule
% \De above is really \De/(\hbar*\omega)
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{energy}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    -\De+(#1+0.5) - (#1+0.5)^2/(4*\De)
    }%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,smooth,xlabel = $r/r_e$, ylabel =$E/\hbar \omega_0$, minor tick num =1, grid=none, no markers, every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west},
every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},domain=0:10, enlargelimits = true,scale=1.5]
\addplot +[thick, samples=50, name path global=MorseCurve] {V(x)};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}{
    \path [name path global=HelperLine-#1] (axis cs: 0,{energy(#1)}) -- (axis cs: 10, {energy(#1)});
    \draw[name intersections={of=MorseCurve and HelperLine-#1}] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Method 2: analytical form of the intersections

Uses the analytical form of the intersections, which is fairly easy to calculate. This is my original post, except I changed `\edef`s to `pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%% Define Potential Function %%%%%%%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\De}{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\re}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{V}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    \De*((1-exp(-\a*(#1-\re)))^2-1)
    }%
}
%%%%%%% Energy Levels %%%%%%%
% energies are given as multiples of \hbar \omega_0 with
% \omega_0 = \a*sqrt(2*\De/\m), where m is the (reduced) mass of the diatomic molecule
% \De above is really \De/(\hbar*\omega)
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{energy}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    -\De+(#1+0.5) - (#1+0.5)^2/(4*\De)
    }%
}
%Upper limit on classical bound state of a given energy
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{rmax}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    (\a*\re+ln( - (\De+sqrt(\De*(#1+\De)))/#1 ) )/\a
    }%
}
%Lower limit on classical bound state of a given energy
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{rmin}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    (\a*\re+ln( (-\De+sqrt(\De*(#1+\De)))/#1 ) )/\a
    }%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,smooth,xlabel = $r/r_e$, ylabel =$E/\hbar \omega_0$, minor tick num =1, grid=none, no markers, every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west},
every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},domain=0:10, enlargelimits = true,scale=1.5]
% \foreach inside axis environment was tricky, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla/17817#17817
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}{
    \draw (axis cs: {rmin( energy(#1) )},{energy(#1)}) -- (axis cs: {rmax(energy(#1))},{energy(#1)});
}
\addplot +[thick, samples=50] {V(x)};
\node[style ={ align=center}] at (axis cs: 7,14) {Morse potential: \\ $V(r) = D_e \left( [1-e^{-a(r-r_e)}]^2-1 \right)$ };
\node[style ={ align=center}] at (axis cs: 7,7) {Energy levels: \\ $E_n = -D_e + \hbar \omega_0 (n+1/2) + \frac{[\hbar \omega_0 (n+1/2)]^2}{4 D_e} $ \\ with $\omega_0 = a \sqrt{2 D_e/m}$ };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With TikZ, without drawing an explicit Morse-potential and with clipping. (The upper blue curve is not really an excited state, but rather a curve that looks alike)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-0.3,0) -- node[sloped,below] {Bond length} (6,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-0.3) -- node[sloped,above] {Enery wavenumbers} (0,5);
    \begin{scope}
        \draw[blue,thick] plot[smooth,domain=0.5:2.5] (\x,{0.2*exp(-20*(\x-1.5)^2)+1)});
        \coordinate (a) at (1.2,1);
        \draw[clip] plot[smooth,tension=0.7] coordinates {(0.5,4) (1,0.1) (3,1.5) (5,2)};
        \foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,6} {
            \draw (0,{2-2/(2*\i)}) -- (5,{2-2/(2*\i)});
        }
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.5,2.5)}]
        \draw[blue,thick] plot[smooth,domain=0.5:2.5] (\x,{0.4*cos(5.5*pi*(\x-1.5) r)^2*sin((\x-1.5) r)^2+1.5});
        \coordinate (b) at (0.7,1.5);
        \path[clip] (0,0) rectangle (5,2);
        \draw[clip] plot[smooth,tension=0.7] coordinates {(0.5,4) (1,0.1) (3,1.5) (5,2)};
        \foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,6} {
            \draw (0,{2-2/(2*\i)}) -- (5,{2-2/(2*\i)});
        }
    \end{scope}
    \draw[red,->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can you do this with an explicit Morse-potential ( I use `\addplot[] expression{...}` in the axis environment, so all my figures are the same in my article).

Comment: Clipping detected...

Comment: @Dries_VB you can precompute your Morse curve in a file where every line is on the format "x_value y_value" and then replace `\draw[clip] plot[smooth,tension=0.7]` by `\draw[clip] plot file{filename}`, or even `\draw[clip] plot function{<gnuplot formula>}`. See §19.2 of the pgfmanual

Comment: @StiffJokes You detected my wording flaw `:-)`

Comment: I see....... :-)

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset
{
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=100,
}

\def\f{(x+1)*(x-2)*(x-2.5)-1}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(5,6)
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray,ticksize=4pt 0]{->}(0,0)(-1,-4)(4.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \begin{psclip}
    {
        \pscustom[linestyle=none]
        {
            \psplot{-1}{3.4}{\f}
            \psline(-1,0|*3.4 {\f})
            \closepath
        }
    }
        \foreach \y in {.5,.7,.8,1,2,3}{\psline(0,\y)(4.5,\y)}% important percent sign 
    \end{psclip}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1}{3.4}{\f}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]