# Intersection of paths with constructed names

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is a "follow up" of the question [naming paths inside a TikZ foreach loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/naming-paths-inside-a-tikz-foreach-loop). I can construct the name of paths, but there are errors when using them to calculate intersection.

An example follows

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\modulargrid}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,   overlay,  ]

%% Trick to name paths:
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/naming-paths-inside-a-tikz-foreach-loop

%% Draw horizontal lines
  \foreach \x in {1,...,6}   {
    \edef\pathhone{name path global=horizontal\x}
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\pathhone] ($
    (current page.north west) 
    + \x-1*(0,20pt-5cm)
    $)
    -- +(20cm, 0);

%% Draw vertical lines
   \edef\pathvone{name path global=vertical\x}
   \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\pathvone] ($
    (current page.south west) 
    + \x-1*(20pt+5cm,0)
    $)
    -- +(0,25cm);
}


\draw (0,0)--(0,0);
\fill[red, opacity=0.5, name intersections={of=vertical1 and horizonta1}]
(intersection-1) circle (2pt) node {1};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\modulargrid
\newpage

\end{document}
```

**The purpose of the code**

The idea behind this code is to make a grid of vertical and horizontal line, calculate the intersection points and them build rectangular shapes with the calculated points (I want to be able to each cell in the grid as a node.)

**EDITED CODE**

I edited the code according to the comment by @jake.
(Sorry for the errors, due to coping an more complex example to a MWE.)

My problem is to use `\i` in the `\fill` command

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\modulargrid}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,   overlay,  ]

%% Trick to name paths:
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/naming-paths-inside-a-tikz-foreach-loop

%% Draw horizontal lines
  \foreach \x[count=\i] in {1,...,6}   {
    \draw[name path global=horizontal\i] ($
    (current page.north west) 
    + \x-1*(0,20pt-5cm)
    $)
    -- +(20cm, 0);

%% Draw vertical lines
   \draw[name path global=vertical\i] ($
    (current page.south west) 
    + \x-1*(20pt+5cm,0)
    $)
    -- +(0,28cm);
 \draw (0,0)--(0,0);
 \fill[red, opacity=0.5, name intersections={of=vertical\i and horizontal\i}]
 (intersection-1) circle (2pt) node {1};
}


 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: The problem (apart from the typo in `horizonta1`) is simply that the first horizontal and the first vertical line do not intersect: The first horizontal line is too high. If you change the `-- +(0,25cm)` to `-- +(0,28cm)`, it works. Note that you don't need to go to all that trouble with the `\edef`: You can simply use `\foreach \x [count=\i] ...` to introduce an integer counter, and then use `\draw [name path global=horizontal\i] (...` in your loop.

Comment: @Jake Still can not compile with your corrections. I edited the code to reflect better my question.

Comment: Well, you can't use the counter `\i` in the `name intersections={of=vertical\i and horizontal\i}`: You have to use `1` there (there's at most one intersection between two straight lines). Could you maybe edit your question to include in more detail what exactly you're trying to achieve? I have the feeling that you're going a very roundabout way, but I don't understand exactly what your final goal is.

Comment: Write `name intersections={of={vertical\i} and {horizontal\i}}` with extra brackets to delimit the names.

Comment: @jake It would be just one intersection point (intersection-1)  between each (horizontal\i, vertical\i) pair of line. I want to find the intersections to define `nodes` with the size and position of the "cells" in this grid.

Comment: @zunbeltz: Ah yeah, you're right, sorry. Andrew's suggestion fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from typos the main problem is in `name intersections`.  The error produced by latex is "Runaway argument?" showing that it is not correctly parsing the arguments.  To fix this write `{vertical\i}` in brackets and similarly `{horizontal\i}`.  The code below is also tidied in various ways that may help with your general problem, and now produces:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\modulargrid}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
%% Draw horizontal lines
  \foreach \x[count=\i] in {1,...,6}   {
    \draw[name path global=horizontal\i] ($
    (current page.north west) 
    + \x*(0,20pt-5cm)
    $)
    -- +(22cm, 0);
%% Draw vertical lines
   \draw[name path global=vertical\i] ($
    (current page.south west) 
    + \x*(20pt+3cm,0)
    $)
    -- +(0,28cm);
%% Dots at intersections
    \fill[red, opacity=0.5,
    name intersections={of={vertical\i} and {horizontal\i}}]
    (intersection-1) circle (5pt) node {};
    }
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\modulargrid
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

The main changes are

- making the `\x` variable multiply the offsets (and using just `\x` rather than `\x - 1`)
- increased size of dot for clarity and providing an empty `node` argument
- changed spacing and lengths and inclusion of background text via `lipsum` package for visualisation

Comment: Thanks it work great. A related problem is that if I take the `\fill` command out of the `\foreach` and place in a loop by itself (with the same `\foreach` statement) the path names are unknown. Shouldn't the `global` key made the name known in all the `tikzpicture`?

Comment: That works fine for me, the `global` option makes the names globally defined and I can use them in other groups and loops.  May be you have a typo in your code.

Comment: I took your code and before the `\fill` command I add `} \foreach \x[count=\i] in {1,...,6}   {`. It work well if don't try to calculate the intersection, but not with same command as in the code.

Comment: Damn! It worked when I change from CVS version of pgf to the TexLive2012 version.