# TikZ: How can I use \foreach variable to reference intersections?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the `\foreach` statement, I generate a set of lines that form a grid. I want to use the loop variables to name the individual paths to later draw something at their intersections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\vlinedist}
\setlength{\vlinedist}{.4cm}
\newlength{\hlinedist}
\setlength{\hlinedist}{.4cm}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
   {
      \draw[name path global/.expanded=h \x] (0,\hlinedist*\x) -- ++(33*\vlinedist,0);
   }
   \foreach \x in {1,...,32} {
      \draw[name path global/.expanded=v \x] (\vlinedist*\x, 0) -- ++(0,11*\hlinedist);
   }
   \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
   {
      \foreach \y in {1,...,32}{
         \draw[name intersections={of=h \x and v \y}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
      }
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/naming-paths-inside-a-tikz-foreach-loop) question I found I must use the `global/.expanded` stuff in order for the paths to be named (whatever the reason). But when trying to reference the different paths in the `intersections={of=h \x and v \y}` part, this does not work, I get the error:

```
Runaway argument?
h \x and v \y \tikz@stop \else \pgfkeys@case@two \fi \fi \fi \pgfkeys@parse \ET
C.
! File ended while scanning use of \tikz@intersect@path@names@parse.
<inserted text>
                \par
<*> file.tex

?
```

Now I know there are other ways to make a grid and place points at some chosen intersections, however that is beside the point, as this is a rather general question of how I can use loop variables to reference named paths in tikz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `intersections={of=h \x and v \y}` where `{h-\x}` and `{v-\y}` should be used. Actually, no dashes in `h-\x` and `v-\y` are required, only the `{ }`. Thanks to @percusse for the kind comment to me.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newlength{\vlinedist}
\setlength{\vlinedist}{.4cm}
\newlength{\hlinedist}
\setlength{\hlinedist}{.4cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
   {
      \draw[name path global/.expanded=h-\x] (0,\hlinedist*\x) -- ++(33*\vlinedist,0);
   }

   \foreach \x in {1,...,32} {
      \draw[name path global/.expanded=v-\x] (\vlinedist*\x, 0) -- ++(0,11*\hlinedist);
   }

   \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
   {
      \foreach \y in {1,...,32}{
         \draw[name intersections={of={h-\x} and {v-\y}}](intersection-1) circle (2pt);
      }
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't need dashes, just braces should do it

Comment: @percusse -- Yes, I confirmed that just now. Thanks. My database had -, therefore use the same structure.

Comment: Ah yes. I could've thought of that.