# Define and use paths inside foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-path

I've looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/naming-paths-inside-a-tikz-foreach-loop) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213083/tikz-how-can-i-use-foreach-variable-to-reference-intersections?rq=1), and I'm unable to compile and use intersections of lines i give name inside the same foreach loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xsidelength}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ysidelength}{1.5}
        \path[draw, dashed,name path global=star2] (0,0) --
            ++(\xsidelength,0) --
            ++(45:\ysidelength) --
            ++(-\xsidelength,0) --
            cycle;

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\halfylength}{\ysidelength/2}
        \coordinate (O) at ($(\xsidelength / 2,0)+(45:\halfylength)$);
        \node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt] at (O) {};

        \foreach \angle[count=\i] in {22.5,0,...,-225}
        {
            \path[name path global/.expanded=line\i] (O) -- ++(\angle:\xsidelength);
            \draw[name intersections = {of {line\i} and star2}](intersection\i) circle (2pt);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first path is drawn, but its name is apparently not known inside the foreach, nor lines defined just a line above

And I've got next errors

```
:26: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/intersection/of {line1} and star2' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

:26: Package tikz Error: I do not know the path named `'. Perhaps you misspelt it.

:26: Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection1 is known.
```

Though, the example is not really minimal, I don't see what is different from answered questions, except i'm trying to reuse names inside the same foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos and a few small mistakes (marked with `!` in code below):

- `\xvsidelength` > `\xsidelength` (typo v)
- `(invtersection\i)` > `(intersection-1)` (typo v & -1 because you are referring to the first intersection of every combination)
- `= {of {line\i}` > `= {of={line\i}` (missing =)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xsidelength}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ysidelength}{1.5}
    \path[draw, dashed,name path global=star2] (0,0) --
    ++(\xsidelength,0) --
    ++(45:\ysidelength) --
    ++(-\xsidelength,0) --
    cycle;

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\halfylength}{\ysidelength/2}
    \coordinate (O) at ($(\xsidelength / 2,0)+(45:\halfylength)$);
    \node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt] at (O) {};

    \foreach \angle[count=\i] in {22.5,0,...,-225}
    {
        \path[name path global/.expanded=line\i] (O) -- ++(\angle:\xsidelength); % !
        \draw[name intersections = {of ={line\i} and star2}](intersection-1) circle (2pt); % !!!
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: typos are not really present (fixed the copy in my question), but the "=" sign and -1 solved the problem.